# Spring Social Google handling error

Tags: spring, spring-social

I am using Spring Social and the Spring Social Google Provider in a project. I am doing an implicit sign up when a user try to login into the application.

Everything is ok until now, the problem is I want to check if the domain of the username's email matches some pattern, if it doesn't I am returning null (the documentation says that, here http://goo.gl/SF2rF0), but doing it I don't have a way to show the error to the user: You can not login with that email.

How can I face this? Should I throw an Exception and handle it in a GlobalHandler (ugly approach)?

Comment: well kind of a strange problem. You want to out source login/password management to another provider but at the same time you want to perform validation on the login field that exists on the provider's site. I think given that problem statement only a 'hack' solution would work here by as you stated either throwing an exception and catching it via global exception handler or Overriding SocialAuthenticationFilter.class#doAuthentication(...) and inserting your validation logic there.

Comment: Certainly, this is not a strange problem, this is very common. Think about it, you are building an internal application where only the users under the company's domain can login. Many others frameworks for other technologies have this. For example: http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/stable/backends/google.html#white-listed-domains-and-email-addresses

Comment: well "strange" may not have been the best word to use but "strange" in the context that you want essentially perform validation on a form field you do not have control over. Regardless, I do not think any white/listed domains feature is built into spring-social or spring-social-google. Mostly likely you will have to come up with your own solution or submit an enhancement request on the github project pages.